# Which ubuntu should I download for my asus x542u?

Tags: downloads

I am new in **Linux**. I do not have much knowledge about Linux. So I would like to learn Linux. I have chosen Linux Ubuntu as I have been heard it is good for learning Linux. But now I can not understand which Ubuntu I should download. There are many versions as well as **LTS** and other term. So, please Help me.

My laptop has **8 gb ram, i5-8250u, up to 3.4 ghz, hdd 1tb**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar). FYI your hardware could run latest version of Ubuntu very well.

Comment: if you want for development then go for Download ubuntu 18.04, otherwise go for 19.04

Answer (score 1):

Download ubuntu 18.04 or 19.04 as it's latest version of ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I am using 19.04 on my new 8 GB notebook. LTS versions are for conservative users. The latest versions, like 19.04, are for users who want to use the newest technologies. Yes, it is true that 19.04 has many bugs. But, while trying to solve these or searching for workarounds you are going to learn much more about this "new" (to you) OS.

Answer (score 0):

There really are only 2 choices:

- The latest version - 19.04 which is supported for the next 7 month or so. After 19.10 is released you will have to update.
- The current LTS (Long Term Support) version 18.04. You can stay on this version until the nex LTS is released. This will be 20.04. LTS versions are released every 2 years, but supported for 5 years.

Which one you choose depends on if you need stable, but not latest versions of software, or you want to want to receive newer, but maybe unstable updates.